# problem regarding identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The following problem confuses me:

> Justify whether the following is true or false:
>
> If a function $f$ is analytic in $\left\lvert z \right\rvert$ $\lt 1$, then
>
> $$f\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n} \bigg)= \bigg(1-\frac{1}{n} \bigg)^2, \quad \forall n.$$

If we consider $g(z)=z^2$, then $g$ is analytic and $g\big(1- \frac{1}{n}\big)=f\big(1-\frac{1}{n}\big)$ but, the limit point is $1$ which is not in the disk.so,we cannot proceed using the identity theorem i.e,f(z)=$z^2$ is not the only function which should satisfy this.please,mention such analytic maps because i can't find one... also,can it happen that if one cannot apply uniqueness theorem in such problems(problem as given above),then there is a surity that we would find more than one analytic function satisfying the given property...

thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: Does the problem say "for every $n$"? Or for some $n$? PLease add more detail about your problem, currently it cannot be answered.

Comment: I think that this is a very hard problem. For example, there exists a function $f$ holomorphic in the disk such that $f(1-1/n^2) = (1-1/n^2)^2$ for all $n$, but $f(z) \neq z^2$ (a construction can be made by using a Blaschke product). Now, since Blaschke condition is not satisfied, there are some troubles in constructing such a counterexample, anyway it is evident that the identity theorem is not enough here.

Comment: What you say cannot possibly be what the problem asks! Simply saying $f(z)=0$ gives a counterexample to your version. What the question "must" be is "does there exist a function $f$ such that...". Or possibly "If $f$ is such that... must $f(z)=z^2$ for all $z$?". Or something. You really need to get the question straight _before_ trying to answer it!

Comment: @david c ulrich:thanks for pointing it out sir,but problem was presented in the same fashion from the textbook i took it.what i really need is if an analytic function satisfies the above condition ,then,is the function f(z)=$z^2$ $\forall$z?

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Let $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is certainly analytic in the unit disk, but 
$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}\neq\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2.
$$